# Restored Pasta Boards

Tags: dough, maintenance

My grandfather's pasta board was in the attic for years.  No mold, it looks perfect, however, I need to clean it, to get rid of dust and smell. I was planning on sanding it.  Once it's sanded, can I use Boos Mystery Oil to complete the process?
If not, what do you recommend?
Thank you.

Comment: 'Pasta board' - it brings memories from the old days, of the electricity- and gas board; not relevant at all, I know. It sounds like something the Italians might had, to ensure the stadard of pasta, if they had been governed by British bureaucracy.

Answer (score 7):

I would not use board oil on a pasta board.

Sand it down (if necessary), give it a good scrub with salt/lemon and let it dry completely.

The board works because it gets used and is a little rough so that the dough does not slide around when kneading or when forming pasta.

Comment: Agreed.  You need the board to grip the pasta when you’re making shapes like orecchiette